# Problem with subquery and max in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Good evening friends,
I have evolved well since my last query on SQL Alchemy.

Currently I have the following queries:

```
# Subquery to get the maximum DtReference value for each IdProduct
stockCurrent = session.query(StockCompany.IdProduct,         func.max(StockCompany.DtReference).label("max_DtReference"), StockCompany.QtyStock)\
              .group_by(StockCompany.IdProduct, StockCompany.QtyStock)\
              .subquery()

# Query that joins the subquery with the original query
query = session.query(ProductCode.CallCode, Product.ProductNm, ProductCompany.CompanyCode, CurrentStock.c.StockQty, CurrentStock.c.max_DtReference)\
           .join(ProductCode, Product.IdProduct == ProductCode.IdProduct)\
           .join(ProductCompany, Product.IdProduct == ProductCompany.IdProduct)\
           .join(CurrentStock, (Product.IdProduct == CurrentStock.c.IdProduct) & (CompanyStock.DtReference == CurrentStock.c.max_DtReference))\
           .filter(ProductCompany.CdCompany == 4)\
           .order_by(desc(ProductCode.CdCall))
```

**The idea is to list only the most current record from the stockCompany table, then do a join with the other tables.**

**The problem is the return.**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\EliasPai\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1900, in _execute_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
File "C:\Users\EliasPai\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 736, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The multipart identifier "InventoryCompany.DtReference" could not be associated. (4104) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Could not prepare one or more statements. (8180)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\EliasPai\Downloads\codes_sv (1)\fone.py", line 53, in 
result = query.all()
File "C:\Users\EliasPai\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2773, in all
return self._iter().all()
File "C:\Users\EliasPai\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemyorm\query.py", line 2916, in _iter
result = self.session.execute(
File "C:\Users\EliasPai\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemyorm\session.py", line 1714, in execute
result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
File "C:\Users\EliasPai\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1705, in _execute_20
return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
File "C:\UsersEliasPai\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 334, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_on_connection(
File "C:\Users\EliasPai\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\engine\base.py", line 1572, in _execute_cl

Answer (score 0):

```
# Subconsulta para obter a última data de referência de cada produto
subquery = session.query(EstoqueEmpresa.IdProduto, func.max(EstoqueEmpresa.DtReferencia).label('DtReferencia'))\
                .group_by(EstoqueEmpresa.IdProduto).subquery()

# Consulta principal para obter os últimos registros de estoque de cada produto
ultimos_estoques = session.query(EstoqueEmpresa.IdProduto, EstoqueEmpresa.CdEmpresa, EstoqueEmpresa.QtEstoque, Produto.NmProduto, Produto.StAtivo, CodigoProduto.CdChamada)\
                        .join(subquery, and_(EstoqueEmpresa.IdProduto == subquery.c.IdProduto, 
                                            EstoqueEmpresa.DtReferencia == subquery.c.DtReferencia))\
                        .join(Produto, Produto.IdProduto == EstoqueEmpresa.IdProduto)\
                        .join(CodigoProduto, CodigoProduto.IdProduto == Produto.IdProduto)\
                        .filter(CodigoProduto.IdTipoCodigoProduto == '00A0000008')\
                        .filter(EstoqueEmpresa.CdEmpresa == 1)\
                        .order_by(desc(EstoqueEmpresa.DtReferencia)).all()
```